# Isolating unmanaged crashes under Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, system.drawing

We have a Mono application under Linux that does image processing on a bunch of files.

For this we (among other things) use System.Drawing, and for the most part it serves us well. Occasionally however, we encounter an image that crashes the application - it is a crash in a native call, and this is immune to try catch. Simplified, a call like

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
```

will cause a crash. The error message looks something like this:

```
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus.GdipLoadImageFromFile (string,intptr&) <0xffffffff>
```

This pulls the whole application down instantly.

We have encountered a few instances that this happens - corrupt GIF files, unexpected headers in TIFF files - to name a few. As we don't have control over the source of the images, we will just have to deal with possible crashes.

**The question:** I would like to isolate the places where we use GDI+ (through System.Drawing) on untrusted files so that it can happily crash without killing the whole application.

I have attempted this through using separate application domains, but I just can't stop the crashes. It is probable that I am doing it wrong!

<sub>Some detail: openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64), Mono version 2.10.2, libgdiplus0 (package) 2.10-30.2, libtiff3 (package) 3.9.4-3.7.1</sub>

---

Please note that the specific issues we experienced was promptly fixed - see comments below. The question still remains though.

I would have liked to somehow isolate a part of the program so that it does not pull the whole thing down - but I fear the only answer is to call a external process as noted in the answer below. I'll leave this as is for a while and then accept that answer!

Comment: I would suggest filing bugs for the images that cause crashes (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) so that the issues can be fixed. Since image parsing has historically been a source for security issues it would also be preferrable if you made the bug private to Xamarin so that you don't disclose a possible security issue.

Comment: Right, logged as http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1752 and http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1753 In the end we sidestepped System.Drawing when we can and rely on Gdk under Mono, which thus far seem much more robust.

Comment: @FPC both issues are now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: **AWESOME!** Very impressed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with some measure of naivety here because I don't know much about Linux... AppDomains (in Windows anyway) reside in the same process.  Try separating out the problematic code into another process, using command lines or some communication mechanism like IPC so that if it crashes, it doesn't bring down the main process, just the child.

Although I've never had an uncatchable exception causing my problems in the past, it sounds like the main process is being killed, which is a layer below the AppDomain idea you said you tried.

Translate to Linuxese where necessary... sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Good suggestion - I had "shelling out" as the last resort! IPC sounds like opening a world of pain - at least to get it working nicely. But I guess I might have to buckle down. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: IPC is actually fairly easy, well it is in Windows with the old .NET Remoting infrastructure.  Personally I'd just command line it and wait for an exit code from the exe, which is something you can control nicely.

Comment: The problem is that speed is a requirement. Shelling out for thousands of image files would be inefficient. IPC - or something like it seems the best option - googling now

Comment: In that case I'd review the use of the library itself and try to replace it.  Get a library that doesn't cause the apocalypse and then you can keep all your code in one exe.  AForge.NET is very good, though I'm not sure what there is for Mono.

Comment: The gdiplus implementation uses (other) native libraries for image loading. Those libraries are quite common, so it's likely that any other managed library that also provides image parsing (on linux) will use the same native library (unless they do it entirely in managed code). My suggestion would be to start an external process and restart it if an image causes a crash, and only try to find a way to do it inproc in a safer way if that is too slow for you.